# How to use where condition with insert query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, where-clause

Query & related error is below :

```
SQL> insert into test(name) values('Raju') where sadd='Hyd';
insert into test(name) values('Raju') where sadd='Hyd'
                                      *
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: it is not insert ,rather use update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to change a value of a table based on a filter use; [UPDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm) is what you want.
And for you:

```
UPDATE test
SET name = 'Raju'
WHERE sadd='Hyd';
```

---

And in another way with using [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) you can update or insertion into a table.

Comment: Why are you linking to the MySQL manual (and showing the MySQL syntax) when Dheeraj is clearly using Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

WHERE clause is used to express a condition, so as to filter out the rows of a table, "where" you have to make the changes.
In your case, use of UPDATE instead of INSERT would fix the error.
Although the entry corresponding to the field value 'Raju' is not present, it would be correct to make that entry using UPDATE command.

Query -

```
UPDATE (test) SET name= 'Raju' WHERE sadd='Hyd';
```